# Get specific text/plain messages using imap_fetchbody

Tags: imap

I'm trying to make website which can display newsletter from Zalora and Groupon

I'm using IMAP.. here's my code :

```
$dapet = imap_search($inbox, 'ALL');
if($dapet){
    rsort($dapet);
    foreach ($dapet as $key) {
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $key);
        @$part = $structure->parts[$key];
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $key,1);
        $message_content = quoted_printable_decode($message);   
        echo $message_content;
    }
}
```

I already determine that newsletter from Zalora and Groupon both are MULTIPART/ALTERNATIVE.. So I use 1 for imap_fetchbody..

this is the result from Zalora : [Result from Zalora](http://postimg.org/image/cbhonokq9/)

it displayed perfectly :) but the result from Groupon is NOT good : [Result from Groupon](http://postimg.org/image/vtv2iu25x/)

My question is :

How can I get only the specific text/plain messages (just the image) from groupon and ignore the string like  `------=_Part_70977513_2074073966.1397213506892 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary.. Bla..Bla..Bla..` ???